# What is the definition of "consecutive roots" of a polynomial function?

Tags: calculus, polynomials

For context, I was about to start solving the following problem from Spivak's Calculus (Chapter 10, problem *27).

> Suppose $a$ and $b$ are **two consecutive roots of a polynomial function**
> $f$, but that $a$ and $b$ are not double roots, so that we can write
> $f(x)=(x-a)(x-b)g(x)$ where $g(a) \neq 0$ and $g(b) \neq 0$.
>
> a) Prove that $g(a)$ and $g(b)$ have the same sign. (Remember that **$a$
> and $b$ are consecutive roots)**.

If the roots were integers, I would understand consecutive as meaning that either $b=a+1$ or $a=b+1$.

In the context of this problem, the roots are real. I'm going to guess consecutive means that there are no roots in between $a$ and $b$.

Assume for proof by contradiction that $g(a)$ and $g(b)$ have different signs. Without loss of generality, consider the case in which $g(a)<0<g(b)$. Then since $g$ is polynomial, and polynomials are continuous, $g$ takes on every value between $g(a)$ and $g(b)$ in the interval $[a,b]$, including $0$. There is thus a root $c \in [a,b]$.

We can thus write $g(x)=(x-c)h(x)$.

So $f(x)=(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)h(x)$, $c$ is thus a root of $f$, and $a$ and $b$ are not consecutive (according to my guessed definition of consecutive roots). $\bot$

Therefore, by proof by contradiction, $g(a)$ and $g(b)$ have the same sign.

Comment: They are roots and there are no roots between them.

Comment: It is presumably talking about real roots ordered by $<$